# Postgres INSERT trigger (same row)

Tags: postgresql

Assume I have the following postgresql table, i.e. `Tbl1`:

In `Tbl1` I have the following attributes (`C_ID` is the unique ID field updated by means of a sequence):

`C_ID`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`, `C_IDr`, `Col5`, etc.

I want to create a trigger that when I `INSERT` a new record, the trigger must fire and set field `C_IDr` (5th column) equal to `C_ID` (based on a certain condition - the condition is the easy part), thus `INSERT` new record: `C_IDr = C_ID`

How do I go about achieving that?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: That's a trivial use for a trigger, and pretty much a copy-and-paste from the examples in the manual. Did you try it before posting, or read the documentation?